# Use jQuery to iterate through JSON array [WP coordinates created by Advanced Custom Fields and JSON API]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a custom field, called coordinates, creating a Google Map inside a Wordpress post. (I am using two plugins to do this: Advanced Custom Fields and JSON API.) I end up with a JSON array like the following:

```
{\"address\":\"425 Northern Ave Thunder Bay, ON\",\"lat\":48.3959003,\"lng\":-89.2453188,\"zoom\":16}
```

In my script, I access the array like so:

```
var thisMap = JSON.parse(val.custom_fields.coordinates);
```

The following returns all the keys inside the array:

```
    for ( val in thisMap ) {
        if (thisMap.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
        console.log(val);
    }
```

I get:
address
lng
lat
zoom

How can I target just the latitude and/or longitude? (i.e. I would like to be able to target just "48.3959003" or "-89.2453188", so I can use them to create a Google Map.)

Comment: `val` is the property, you need to access the value of the property, right?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{\"address\":\"425 Northern Ave Thunder Bay, ON\",\"lat\":48.3959003,\"lng\":-89.2453188,\"zoom\":16}'); 
alert('latitude:'+obj.lat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qz9q4/)**

It returns a javascript object, and you can access its properties directly

```
var val = "{\"address\":\"425 Northern Ave Thunder Bay, ON\",\"lat\":48.3959003,\"lng\":-89.2453188,\"zoom\":16}";    
var thisMap = JSON.parse(val);

console.log(thisMap);
console.log(thisMap.lat);
console.log(thisMap.lng);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. I really thought I'd been down that route. Thanks so much!